# Devise controller how to change layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I change layout in the devise controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to subclass the controller like in the following:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  layout 'my_layout'  

end
```

And change the routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions"}
```

Comment: Then I get this error: Template is missing

Missing template sessions/new with. I have changed the devise view folder to sessions

Comment: You have to change the `devise/sessions` folder to `sessions'.

Answer (score 2):

First, set your routes. For example:

```
devise_for :users, 
             :controllers => { 
                      :registrations => "users/registrations", 
                      :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks",
                      :sessions => "users/sessions"}
```

Second, create the file with the controller:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController  
  layout=>"my_layout"
end
```

Third, create the views for your controller in views/users/sessions. For instance, new.html.haml

```
=form_for user=User.new, :as=>"user", :url=>session_path("user") do |f|
  =f.label :email, 'email'
  =f.text_field :email
  =f.label :password, 'password'
  =f.password_field :password
  =link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path("user")
  .button_container{:style=>'border-top: none;'}
    =f.submit "sign in", :class=>'submit_button'
```

Hope this help.